# Backbone model destroy url not passing model id

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my app, I want to delete a model from a collection and call "this.model.destroy" in my view. However I get a 405 response when triggering the function and the url of the response does not contain the model's id. From what I've understood from the documentation, Backbone creates the url based on the "Collection url + model id". I've fixed the problem by passing in the url to the destroy method, but know that this is not the best way. 
Somehow I feel that this should work without my "hack".
The backend requires a Id when a DELETE request is sent.
How can I accomplish this using Backbone's best practices?

```
        My.Model._entity = Backbone.Model.extend({

        initialize: function(options) {
            if (options.created && typeof options.created === 'string') {
                this.set('created', new Date(options.created));
            }

            if (options.modified && typeof options.modified === 'string') {
                this.set('modified', new Date(options.modified));
            }
        },

        defaults: function() {
            return {
                created: new Date(),
                modified: new Date()
            };
        }
    });


    My.Model.cartItem = My.Model._entity.extend({

        defaults: function () {
            var _def = My.Model.cartItem.__super__.defaults.apply(this, arguments);
            return _.defaults(_def, {
                description: "",
                title: "",
                image: "",
                price: 0,
                quantity: 0,
                itemId: ''
            });
        },

        url: '/checkout/item'
    });

    My.Collection.CartItem = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: My.Model.cartItem,
        url: '/checkout/item'

    });
```

Comment: is `itemId` your id attributes? if so, add `idAttribute: 'itemId'` to your model definition: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

Answer (score 3):

Actually setting urlRoot to a function is how I got around it.

```
urlRoot: function () {
        return "/checkout/item";
    }
```

Apparently this allows the Collection to construct the url.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'My.Model.cartItem' should not override the `url` property with a string (or override it at all). By default (seen [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-69)) the model's url is a function which combines its id property to the end of the collection's url base (which you already have defined).

If you wanted to specify a custom url path to be combined with your model Id, you could still do so using "`urlRoot`" rather than "`url`". You should be fine just removing '`url`' here though.

Comment: This overrides the collection url and triggers an error if I want to post.

Comment: What change did you make to the model, and what was the error it generated?

Comment: I changes the url in my model to 'urlRoot: function () { return "/checkout/item"; }

Comment: you shouldn't need to have either the urlRoot or the url property defined on the model because it will pull the 'url' property from the collection. If you look at the source you'll see why urlRoot will work correctly but is unnecessary if the model is in a collection : http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-69